# Extracting Date Time phrases using Stanza

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

this is my first question here. I am trying to understand if this problem should be solved within Stanza or if it needs additional Regex code.

I applied Named Entity Recognition in Stanza to extract the relevant date/time entities from a piece of text as such:

"Mary and her friend watched a movie at 3:00PM on Thursday. She and her friend enjoyed it a lot. After waking up, Mary and her friend made pancakes for breakfast. They ate pancakes at 9:00AM. They were very tired afterwards. They slept at night."

Stanza correctly identifies "3:00PM on Thursday", "9:00AM", and "night" correctly. However, I would also like to be able to extract a few words preceding or succeeding the output, as the date-time markers by itself are not very useful. So for example, "ate pancakes at 9:00AM" or "watched a movie at 3:00PM on Thursday."

Thank you!

Here is the relevant code:

````
def show_ents(doc):
    if doc.entities:
        for entity in doc.entities:
            if entity.type == 'TIME' or entity.type == 'DATE':
                print("{} -> {}".format(entity.text, entity.type))
                entities.append(entity.text + ':' + entity.type)  
                
            else: print('No named entities found.')
                
        return entities
    else: print('No named entities found.') ```

T
````